# Entity Reference & View

Tags: views, entities

I am in the process of setting up a listing and review type scenario.  I have set up the separate entity types, one for the listing, and three for the types of reviews.  I kind of get how (from here and other sites) to set up these relationships using entity reference.

What I don't understand, is when I have a published listing, and I want the user to navigate to one of the three reviews, how do I make this happen?  ie what do I do to set up this link and in what module?  Is there a 'link' field to the review type, and the 'entity reference prepopulate' will take care of it?

So when it comes time to publish, I will have the listing and three columns for the different types of reviews.

Any help is much appreciated, new to drupal, having trouble connecting all the dots...

Comment: You can manually generate in a views field using tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Entity Connect Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect)

> Entity Connect now expands both Entity reference and References
>   (node_reference and user_reference) fields by adding "add new content"
>   and "edit current content" buttons.

Exactly what you need.